# Write each data.table column to separate text files in R

Tags: r

I have a read a csv file into a data.table that is as follows:

```
      Cat1 Cat2 Cat3   Country   file_name
1:    A    E    B      Canada    first
2:    C    B           India     Second
3:    C                Canada    third
4:    B                Ireland   Fourth
5:    C    A           India     fifth
6:    A    C    F     Canada     Sixth
```

I am using following code to write the contents of each row to a separate text file:

```
lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) write.table(df[i], file= paste0("./TextFiles/", df[i, file_name], ".txt"), row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F))
```

The output I am getting right now is as follows for "Sixth.txt" (for example):

```
A C F Canada Sixth
```

However, I want the text to be as follows:

```
Cat1
A

Cat2
C

Cat3
F

Country
Canada
```

Is there a way to get this output without nesting a lot of *lapply*?

Trying the code:

```
lapply(df, function(i) i)
```

gives the output:

```
$Cat1
[1] "A" "C" "C" "B" "C" "A"

$Cat2
[1] "E" "B" ""  ""  "A" "C"

$Cat3
[1] "B" ""  ""  ""  ""  "F"

$Country
[1] "Canada"  "India"   "Canada"  "Ireland" "India"   "Canada" 

$file_name
[1] "first"  "Second" "third"  "Fourth" "fifth"  "Sixth"
```

So, I have a feeling it is possible to get the names of the columns before the content and also to insert lines before each column entry. However, I am unable to find a way to do it.

Comment: Do you want it to be printed vertically? like we get to see in console or is it fine like each row in separate text file with their column names like below??  Let me know if you want some changes in the below result.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian: I don't want them to be in the form of a table like in your answer below. Actually, I will import the text files to RQDA. So, I need the rows to be printed one after the other like I showed in the question.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian: Thanks. It works. Is there a way to use the data in one of the columns as file name as I showed in the question?

Comment: You want it without file extension or with file extension? Just to confirm

Comment: Please check the edited answer and accept it if its correct. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you should edit the Title of this question to "Write each data.table row to separate text files in list form in R"

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian: Good suggestion about the title, but I don't think the technical aspect (conversion to list) of how it is being done is an important part of the title. The technical part is however a very crucial part of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118203/discussion-between-dipto-and-sowmya-s-manian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply()` function to make each row to a list and then output it using `sink()` inside `for` loop. Then check your working directory to see the files `File1.txt`, `File2.txt`, `File3.txt` and `File4.txt`. Filename can be extracted using `strsplit()` and can be added to the file output using `Result[[i]]$file_name`

```
  library(data.table)
  df <- data.frame(a=1:4,b=9:12,c=3:6,d=0:3)
  df <- data.table(df)

  df
  #    a  b c d
  # 1: 1  9 3 0
  # 2: 2 10 4 1
  # 3: 3 11 5 2
  # 4: 4 12 6 3

  Result = apply(df,1,as.list)


 for(i in 1:length(Result)){
 sink(paste("File",i,".txt",sep=""))
 Result[[i]]$file_name <- strsplit(paste("File",i,".txt",sep=""),"\\.")[[1]][1]
 print(Result[[i]])
 sink()
 }
```

[image]